# cakephp unable to sort on afterfind virtual fields with paginate

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I have a query that I am running through paginate.  This query contains a model ("PaymentException") that has an afterfind method that tacks on a copy of the last "ExceptionWorkflowLog", and calls it "LastWorkflowLog".

The query being passed to paginate:

```
    $this->paginate = array(
        'fields' => array(
            'PaymentException.*', 'Procedure.id', 'Procedure.cpt',
            'Procedure.expected_amount', 'Procedure.allowed_amount', 'Procedure.difference_amount',
            'Claim.id', 'Claim.number', 'Payer.abbr'
        ),
        'limit' => 50,
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'procedures',
                'alias' => 'Procedure',
                'conditions' => array('Procedure.id = PaymentException.procedure_id')
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'claims',
                'alias' => 'Claim',
                'conditions' => array('Claim.id = Procedure.claim_id')
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'payers',
                'alias' => 'Payer',
                'conditions' => array('Payer.id = Procedure.payer_id')
            ),
            array(
                'table' => 'groups',
                'alias' => 'Groups',
                'conditions' => array('Groups.id = Claim.group_id')
            )
        ),
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'contain' => array('ExceptionWorkflowLog')
    );
```

The resulting array (from the query that combines both "PaymentException", "ExceptionWorkflowLog", and "LastWorkflowLog")  looks like below:

```
0 =>
  'PaymentException' => array(fields and values),
  'ExceptionWorkflowLog' => array(of ExceptionWorkflowLogs),
  'LastWorkflowLog' => array(fields and values of the last indexed ExceptionWorkflowLog)
1 => ...
```

ExceptionWorkflowLog is mapped to PaymentException by PaymentException.id.  It's a many to one relationship (thus the array of results under the ExceptionWorkflowLog).

I would like to use paginate to sort on the "updated" field on either the last indexed ExceptionWorkflowLog or the LastWorkflowLog.

Is there a way to do this with paginate?  Currently, if I set the table heading to point to  "LastWorkflowLog.updated", the query returns false because the query doesn't know what "LastWorkflowLog" is.

Comment: Are you showing a table of `PaymentException` or `ExceptionWorkflowLogs`? What's the relation between the two models?

Comment: That's showing a query that combines everything I need to display.  I'll update the question with the relationship info.

Comment: You could try binding `ExceptionWorkflowLog` as a `hasOne` with a condition to grab your last indexed one and alias it as `LastWorkflowLog`. Then if cake doesnt, force it to do a join instead of a second query and that should work.

Comment: Do I need to remove the contain for ExceptionWorkflowLog?

Comment: Are you just grabbing all ExceptionWorkflowLogs currently just to get the last one or are you using all the records there for something else? At a min, you would have to add `LastWorkflowLog` to contain, and remove `ExceptionWorkflowLog` if you dont need all of them.

Comment: Currently that's just there to get the last one in the afterFind method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13531/discussion-between-tigrang-and-tubaguy50035)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this has a couple hundred views, I figured I'd come back and post what I did.  CakePHP's handling of joins is absolutely terrible.  I rewrote the query to not use joins, but use contains.  That seems to have solved it.  I feel dirty.